# Hover wiggle effect: how to stop a self-calling function on mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, loops, setinterval

I am trying to replicate the wiggling text found in the hover states featured on the website Bureau.cool on the bottom of the info page
https://bureau.cool/#!/info

Here is where I'm at so far:
https://codepen.io/isaidicanshout/pen/QYxxJV

I originally tried using CSS animation with an add/remove class, which had the desired effect EXCEPT the effect would "snap" on and off immediately, rather than stopping/starting smoothly.

So I started from scratch using an infinite repeating function that toggles the transform: scaleY class over and over, however I am having trouble getting the function to stop once you stop hovering.

**My question: How do I create a function that repeats forever while hovered, but stops immediately when you stop hovering?**

```
// MAKES WORDS WIGGLE ON HOVER
function wiggler() {
  // Hover on .wiggle class
  $('.wiggler').hover(function(index) {
    var currentHover = $(this);
    console.log(currentHover);
    function repeatForever() {
      // Finds all spans inside the hovered element, does something after a pause
      // uses jquery-timing.min.js
      $(currentHover).children('span').each($).wait(15, function(index) {
        // Toggle the animation class
        $(this).toggleClass('ani');
      });
      // repeats forever
      window.setTimeout(repeatForever, 300);
    };
    // starts the loop
    repeatForever();
  },function() {
    var currentHover = $(this);
    console.log(currentHover);
    $(currentHover).children('span').each($).wait(15, function(index) {
      // trying to stop it from happening, but to no avail
      $(this).clearQueue().removeClass('ani');
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clear the timeout to avoid the infinite loop:

```
function wiggler() {
  //note that I use this here but you could use a standard variable
  this.timeout = null
  let _this = this
  $('.wiggler').hover(function(index) {
      ...
      function repeatForever() {
       ...
         _this.timeout = window.setTimeout(repeatForever, 300);
       }
    };
    // starts the loop
    repeatForever();
  },function() {
    ...
    if (_this.timeout) window.clearTimeout(_this.timeout)
  });
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much!! It starts and stops just fine. My next task will be to figure out a better way to stagger the effect than jquery timing .wait() since it seems unreliable.